# Powershell v2 remoting and delegation

Tags: powershell, delegation, powershell-remoting

I have installed Powershell V2 on 2 machines and run Enable-PsRemoting on both of them. Both machines are Win 2003 R2 and are joined to the same active directory domain and I can successfully run commands remotely. So PS remoting is working between the local server and remote server.

But when I try to access a share on a 3rd server (dir \someOtherServer\builds), which is also Win 2003 R2 and joined to the same active directory, I get the error:
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\someOtherServer\builds' because it does not exist.

So what does it take to get this "hop" to work? Is it the delegation settings (in the active directory) to the remote machine? Are there any settings that can be done when creating a  PSSession that will make the hop to work?

Answer (score 2):

I addressed this issue for Workgroups in a [blog post](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!7003.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=571213418).  I think the info should apply to domains but I haven't tested in a domain.  Anyway, see if it helps.  FYI, the solution involves Enable-WSManCredSSP and the Authentication parameter to Enter-PSSession.

Comment: The problem here is that the servers that I am dealing with are all Win 2003 and CredSSP is not available on those platforms. 

BTW: I am a regular reader of your blog. Thanks for the response (and PSCX 1.2, and under the hood of LINQ presentation).

Answer (score 0):

It's can be many causes of that. If kerberos auth, check the time on all servers. It must be sync. It may be DNS resolution problem. Need more detailed problem description/

Sorry fo bad english :). If something wrong, please correct me :)